# How to add pagination to JSON table in HTML using JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, json

HTML

This code retrieves the JSON data from the external source and displays it inside the table, it has total 50 rows of data, now I need to add pagination to the page that shows 10 data rows per page without losing the current functions[Drop-down function, Console log etc..], any help will be apprecieated, thank you!

NOTE: external JSON data doesn't work on live previews, please open the index page directly on browser.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
      
    <select class="more"></select>
    <table class="table table-hover pagination-page" id="table" style="width:100%"> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>FirstName</th>
          <th>LastName</th>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>E-mail</th>    
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>gender</th>
          <th>maritial status</th>
          
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
      <span id="PreValue" class="pagination-page">Previous</span> |
      <span id="nextValue" class="pagination-page">next</span> 
  </div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        fetch('http://fakeapi.jsonparseronline.com/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {
      console.log('Output: ', out);
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
    var users= [];
        
  $.getJSON('http://fakeapi.jsonparseronline.com/users', function(data) {
      users = data;
      buildSelect();
      listUsers(1, 10);
  });
       
        
        
  function buildSelect() {
      var sdata = "";
      $.each(users, function (key, value) {
        if (key % 10 === 0) {
          sdata += `<option data-start-index="${key + 1}" data-end-index="${key + 10}">${key + 1} - ${key + 10}</option>`;
        }
      });
      $(".more").html(sdata);
  }
  
  function listUsers(start, end) {
    var udata = "";
    
    $.each(users.slice(start-1, end), function (key, value) {
        udata += "<tr>" +
                     "<td>" + value.id + "</td>" +
                     "<td>" + value.firstName + "</td>" +
                     "<td>" + value.lastName + "</td>" +
                     "<td>" + value.username + "</td>" +
                     "<td>" + value.email + "</td>" +
                     "<td>" + value.age + "</td>" +
                     "<td>" + value.gender + "</td>" +
                     "<td>" + value.phone + "</td>" +
                 "</tr>";
    }); 
      
    $('#table').html(udata);
      $("#table tbody tr").click(function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var $text = $row.find("td").text();
        alert($text);
      });
  }
 
  buildSelect();
  listUsers(1, 10);
  
  $(document).on("change",".more",function() {
    startIndex = $(":selected", this).attr("data-start-index");
    endIndex = $(":selected", this).attr("data-end-index");
    listUsers(startIndex, endIndex);
  });
```

Comment: Are you open to using external libraries? You might want to check out: https://datatables.net/

Comment: thank you, but I need to do it without using libraries, I wrote a function but that doesn't work.